# Upgrading Anaconda Python version from 3.4 to 3.6 *offline*?

Tags: python, anaconda, upgrade, offline

I am on a secure Linux (CentOS) environment without internet access. The Anaconda installed has python version 3.4 and I need to upgrade it to 3.6. Is there an easy way to do this offline?

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the version number of an Anaconda distribution that includes
   python 3.6 in the [release
   notes](http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/reference/release-notes/).
2. Download the full installer of that Anaconda distribution
   version from the [installers
   archive](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/).
3. Uninstall the existing Anaconda distribution on your machine and install the new one using the installer file.

Comment: Thank you. Since I don't know of a clean removal procedure for Anaconda, I would rather upgrading it than removing and reinstalling it.

Comment: Though possible, that would be a lot more manual effort. See [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/5246#issuecomment-299998815).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Github helpful discussion.